# using gdal /vsis3/ on aws lambda fails

Tags: gdal, lambda, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS lambda to process some files stored in an S3 bucket using GDAL.

I have used information in the previous question [enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201831/how-to-efficiently-access-files-with-gdal-from-an-s3-bucket-using-vsis3/202887) to test that I can read the file using /vsis3/

The difficulty has been to get GDAL working in AWS Lambda which is a Linux RHEL, which meant I have had to build from source.

I used the following config for that
    ./configure --disabled-shared --enable-static

Which gave me the executables that I can include in my code zip to upload to Lambda.

I have tested the GDAL executable using a local file within my code zip and that works, eg gdalinfo image.tif

However, trying to use

```
gdalinfo --config AWS_REGION "region" --config AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID "KEY" --config AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY "SECRET"/vsis3/bucket/key
```

causes an error message of

```
Unable to open datasource `/vsis3/bucket/key' with the following drivers.
```

Does anyone know a solution?

My fear is that /vsis3/ requires something that I am not using in the build process

### EDITS

I managed to change my GDAL build to include curl (--with-curl) and have successfully used that from lambda to the S3 file using

```
gdalinfo "/vsicurl/image.tif"
```

But the vsis3 still fails

Comment: Is using rasterio an option? There are [tutorials for rasterio lambda containers](https://github.com/perrygeo/lambda-rasterio) which seem pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Kersten possibly although my NodeJS is better than my python, so will investigate rasterio further. Thanks for pointing me in that direction

Comment: Maybe you need to override `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` on the lambda?  Grep [cpl_vsi.h doc](http://www.gdal.org/cpl__vsi_8h.html) for more info.

Comment: @tjmgis, did you provide AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID configuration options? http://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html#gdal_virtual_file_systems_vsis3

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda takes privileges to S3 service (including GDAL/OGR vsis3) from IAM role that runs the Lambda function. By default there is only privilege to run the Lambda function, but you can create your own IAM role having Lambda exec + S3 read privileges and assign it to execution role of your Lambda. Then you don't need to set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID. The /vsicurl worked for you probably because you set public access to the source data on S3 but /vsis3 uses another mechanism...