# Open raster file with GDAL on google cloud storage bucket returns None

Tags: gdal, google-cloud

I have a raster file on a google cloud storage bucket and I want to open it with GDAL.  I am trying this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import client

#ensure file exists
name = '1.tif'
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
stats = storage.Blob(bucket=bucket, name=name).exists(storage_client)
print(stats)
```

This returns `True` and the full path is `gs://my-bucket/1.tif`

But when I do this

```
gdal.Open('gs://my-bucket/1.tif')
```

it returns `None`

I can open the file correctly just fine when I read it from my google drive, so this seems to be an issue only on google cloud storage

Comment: Have you already configured the AWS credentials in your environment (accesskeyid, secretaccesskey, region, etc.)? This thread may help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201831/how-to-efficiently-access-files-with-gdal-from-an-s3-bucket-using-vsis3

Comment: It is google cloud storage, not AWS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCS buckets are implemented as a GDAL virtual filesystem, so you'll want to update the filepath to:

```
gdal.Open('/vsigs/my-bucket/1.tif')
```

But as @Kartograaf mentions, you may also need to set some additional configuration parameters if your bucket requires authentication.

Alternatively, [rasterio appears to handle the `gs://` notation](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/pull/1577).

Comment: Thanks, @James. In case it's useful to others, I found the configuration parameters for authentication here: https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsigs-google-cloud-storage-files